# Magento2 How to set pretty url for advance search

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2

i need to change the url patter in advance search in magento2 like : catalogsearch/advanced/result/name/simple/ in default is gives the as query string but i need to change this.

how can i do this ?

can any one suggest the better solution for this ?

thanks in advance for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello i have spent a lot of time on this and figure out a solution for this.please see the below changes for this : 
1) you need to change the method from get to post in form.phtml by ovverride that phtml file.

2) you need to ovverride the Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Advanced\Result.php file as below code :

use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Advanced as ModelAdvanced;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\UrlFactory;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Result extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * Url factory
     *
     * @var UrlFactory
     */
    protected $_urlFactory;

```
/**
 * Catalog search advanced
 *
 * @var ModelAdvanced
 */
protected $_catalogSearchAdvanced;

/**
 * Construct
 *
 * @param Context $context
 * @param ModelAdvanced $catalogSearchAdvanced
 * @param UrlFactory $urlFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    ModelAdvanced $catalogSearchAdvanced,
    UrlFactory $urlFactory,
    UrlInterface $urlBuilder
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_catalogSearchAdvanced = $catalogSearchAdvanced;
    $this->_urlFactory = $urlFactory;
    $this->_urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
}

/**
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
 */
public function execute()
{
    try {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        if(!empty($post)){
            $newurl = $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl('catalogsearch/advanced/result1/',['name' => $post['name'],'sku'=>$post['sku']]);
            $params = ['name' => $post['name'],'sku'=>$post['sku']];
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            header('Location:'.$newurl);
            $resultRedirect->setPath($this->_redirect->redirect($newurl,$params));    

            return $resultRedirect;
        }
    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        $defaultUrl = $this->_urlFactory->create()
            ->addQueryParams($this->getRequest()->getQueryValue())
            ->getUrl('*/*/');
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->error($defaultUrl));
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

}

3) you need to create a new route for as i create result1 in vendor itself and you need to put the code below :

use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Advanced as ModelAdvanced;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\UrlFactory;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Result1 extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * Url factory
     *
     * @var UrlFactory
     */
    protected $_urlFactory;

```
/**
 * Catalog search advanced
 *
 * @var ModelAdvanced
 */
protected $_catalogSearchAdvanced;

/**
 * Construct
 *
 * @param Context $context
 * @param ModelAdvanced $catalogSearchAdvanced
 * @param UrlFactory $urlFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    ModelAdvanced $catalogSearchAdvanced,
    UrlFactory $urlFactory,
    UrlInterface $urlBuilder
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_catalogSearchAdvanced = $catalogSearchAdvanced;
    $this->_urlFactory = $urlFactory;
    $this->_urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
}

/**
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
 */
public function execute()
{
    try {
        $params = $this->_request->getParams();
        $this->_catalogSearchAdvanced->addFilters($params);//$this->getRequest()->getQueryValue()
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        $defaultUrl = $this->_urlFactory->create()
            ->addQueryParams($this->getRequest()->getQueryValue())
            ->getUrl('*/*/');
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->error($defaultUrl));
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

}

4) you need to create a same copy of the catalogsearch_advanced_result.xml to create catalogsearch_advanced_result1.xml

and here you will see the pretty url in browser as what ever you want .

[image]

see the screenshot i attach of my result you are able to see the url in that capture image